# How to use Toast Notifications with .Net Maui

Tags: c#, toast, maui

I'm trying to show a ToastNotification in a brand new .Net Maui App.

I'm following the instructions from Microsoft about [Sending a local toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop).

I'm able to successfully create one with the code from step 2:

```
// Requires Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package version 7.0 or greater
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
    .AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
    .Show(); // Not seeing the Show() method? Make sure you have version 7.0, and if you're using .NET 6 (or later), then your TFM must be net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 or greater
```

However when I add the code below (from Step 3), the `Show()` method throws this exception:

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.dll.

"Failed to register notification activator"
```

Here's the code from Step 3 that broke it. I believe it's failing at `ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated`:

```
// Listen to notification activation
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs =>
{
    // Obtain the arguments from the notification
    ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);

    // Obtain any user input (text boxes, menu selections) from the notification
    ValueSet userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;

    Debug.WriteLine("Toast Activated!");
};
```

Ultimately I'm trying to add buttons to the ToastNotification and run code when they're selected.

Edit:
It was failing at `ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated` because I didn't enable the ToastActivator in my windows project. I put a link to the solution in my answer

Comment: Please add to question the relevant code. This ensures this Q&A is useful in the future, if those links become invalid. It also allows people trying to help to verify that you have accurately followed those instructions; sometimes an overlooked detail is the problem.

Comment: Second, the link you gave is for a **"Windows Desktop" app** or a **"Windows UWP" app** (depending on which part of instructions you used). NEITHER case is a "Maui app". Third, the error message mentions **UWP**. Maui is **not compatible** with UWP. In app's **"Windows"** folder, put code from **"Desktop"** part of doc. ALTERNATIVELY, search for Maui-specific Toast implementations. [I have not used Toast in Maui, so I don't have any further knowledge or suggestions about this.]

Comment: I've updated the post to contain the relevant code. And yeah there isn't much documentation on using ToastNotifications in Maui. Most of it is very basic template code or code for other platforms like WPF or UWP. There is enough built in stuff for it that I'm sure this should be able to work

Comment: So the "UWP" in the name does not indicate a package intended for use with UWP (only), but rather indicates implementation of an API from UWP, on various other platforms? [As I mentioned, Maui is not compatible with UWP.] Perhaps double-check that fact, before continuing. The Nuget's page does NOT show compatibility with any Xamarin platforms, so I'm not sure how it would work with Maui. Even if you get past that exception, the notification might not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent the last few days researching and was able to figure it out. I created a demo project on Github to help explain/demonstrate how to get it to work. Here's the link to that: [Using Toast Notifications with .Net Maui](https://github.com/gurrenm3/Toast-Notifications-with-.Net-Maui).

The quick answer is 2 things are needed:

1. Add the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` nuget package
2. Edit the appmanifest for the Windows Project and add support for the ToastActivator. Check this link for more info: [Enabling Toast Activator](https://github.com/gurrenm3/Toast-Notifications-with-.Net-Maui#enable-toast-activator).