# How to send a notification message to system tray using .NET MAUI windows application

Tags: c#, maui, system-tray

I'm developing an Android / Windows application which need to alert the user when a timer times out.
On Windows side i'm facing a issue where the notification on system tray doesn't pops out.
I followed a bunch of examples over the internet with no luck.
Some of them suggested to use the communitytoolkit.winui.notifications, others to follow the github project https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne

Thanks in advance.
Paolo

Below you can see the code that should show up the notification:

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using WeatherTwentyOne.Services;

namespace WeatherTwentyOne.WinUI;

public class NotificationService : INotificationService
{
    public void ShowNotification(string title, string body)
    {
        new ToastContentBuilder()
            .AddToastActivationInfo(null, ToastActivationType.Foreground)
            .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/dotnet_bot.png"))
            .AddText(title, hintStyle: AdaptiveTextStyle.Header)
            .AddText(body, hintStyle: AdaptiveTextStyle.Body)
            .Show();
    }
}
```

No errors, no notifications either...
Someone knows if there's any other solution i can try ?

Comment: Maui toolkit toast do exactly that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/toast)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fit my needs, because the TOAST is something that appear inside the application window. Actually i'm looking for a notification system when the application is working in background (something like android notification) as the system tray notification on desktop applications.

Comment: I believe that what Toast is for, you can see [there](https://youtu.be/rFJHY7YK6V4?t=466) that it does show outside of the window. I don't know if it work while in background but I don't see why it shouldn't. More info there : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview

Answer (score 0):

Toasts are timed reminders that appear at the bottom of the screen. It provides a [custom notification time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/custom-timestamps-on-toasts?tabs=appsdk), which can be run in the background. You can check the official documentation ([App notification content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=appsdk)) for more information.

For some usage methods, you can refer to the answer in the thread ([How to use Toast Notifications with .Net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102160/how-to-use-toast-notifications-with-net-maui#:%7E:text=I%20spent%20the%20last%20few%20days%20researching%20and%20was%20able%20to%20figure%20it%20out.%20I%20created%20a%20demo%20project%20on%20Github%20to%20help%20explain/demonstrate%20how%20to%20get%20it%20to%20work.%20Here%27s%20the%20link%20to%20that%3A%20Using%20Toast%20Notifications%20with%20.Net%20Maui.)).